# Creating a lottery draw method

Tags: java

**Hello.**


I'm working on a lottery system in a game that I'm working on.


My goal is to get a player randomly based on their amount input and the total value of the lottery pot at the moment of the drawing. E.G Pot is 100k, Player1 has put in 10k, and Player2 has put in 20k, meaning Player 1 has 1/10 chance of winning and Player2 has a 2/10 chance of winning.


`totalPot`, this is the total value of the pot

`randomNR`, this is a random number generation

`userInput`, this is the total input that the user has put into the lottery.

`player`, this is the player who inputted the amount above

I have already tried this:

```
public static void drawLottery() {

    int totalPot = lotteryPot - 250;
    int randomNR = Misc.randomInt(0, lotteryPot);

    List<Player> keys = new ArrayList<Player>(lotteryEntries.keySet());
    Collections.shuffle(keys);

    for(int i = 0; i < totalPot;) {
        for (Player o : keys) {
            i += lotteryEntries.get(o);
            if (i >= randomNR) {
                System.out.println("Winner: " + o.getUsername() + " -> Random number: " + randomNR);
            }
            break;
        }
        break;
    }

}
```

But that just caused the same player to be drawn over and over again.

I don't know what to do and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're printing player.getUsername(), where are you setting the player variable? You should be setting it inside the loop if I understand what you want to do correctly.

Comment: just update your method to drawLottery(Player player)

Comment: Your question is vague and makes no sense and is so wrong. You are doing player.getUsername() which is equal to user who inputs data. So in every case current user who is feeding data is gonna be the winner.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the post.

Comment: what is that? `int i = 0; i  entry : lotteryEntries.entries()`

Comment: That's the multimap storing all lottery entries, parameter one being the player, and the second the amount input.

Comment: Does the total amount of the pot depend on the players? E.g. player 1 pots 10k, player 2, 20k en player 3 100k => total lottery pot = 130k?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over all the lottery entries and keep a cumulative total. The first time the cumulative total exceeds the winning number is the player that has won.

For example:

```
Player 1: 20
Player 2: 30
Player 3: 50
Player 4: 10
```

The winning number is chosen to be 51. The cumulative total starts at 20. This is not greater than 51, so player 1 has not won. Then we increment to 50. Not greater than 51, player 2 has not won. Then we increment to 100 which greater than 51 so player 3 has won.

```
public static Player getWinner(int winningNumber, Map<Player, Integer> lotteryEntries)
{
    int cumulativeProbability = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<Player, Integer> entry : lotteryEntries.entrySet())
    {
        cumulativeProbability += entry.getValue();
        if (cumulativeProbability >= winningNumber)
        {
            return entry.getKey();
        }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Winning number not within total pot size");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the pot to ponderate your random choice. Pick a number inside the pot. define a range in the pot for every player. If the picked number is in the range, this player is the winner.

For example, the pot is 30. Player 1 put 10 and player 2 put 20. You pick a random number between 0 and 30. Let's say random gives us 23. The range corresponding to player 1 is 0 to 10 and the range corresponding to player 2 is 10 to 30. Then player 2 has won.

This should look like this :

```
//pick a random number inside the pot
Random rand = new Random();
int randNum = rand.nextInt(totalPot);

//Define the pot range corresponding to a player
int rangeStart = 0;
int rangeEnd = 0;

//go through all enties (all players)
for(Entry entry : lotteryEntries.entries()) {
    //Define the range corresponding to this player
    value = entry.getValue()
    rangeStart = rangeEnd;
    rangeEnd += value;

    //If the picked random num is in the range, this player is the winner
    if( randNum >= rangeStart && randNum < rangeEnd) {
       System.out.println("Winner: "  + entry.getKey().getUsername()):
       System.out.println("randNum: " + randNum);
       break;
     }
}
```

Comment: My goal is to get a player randomly based on their amount input and the total value of the lottery pot at the moment of the drawing.
E.G Pot is 100k, Player1 has put in 10k, and Player2 has put in 20k, meaning Player 1 has 1/10 chance of winning and Player2 has a 2/10 chance of winning.

Comment: @AaronNoHuanKnows please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50037646/edit) your question with what you have precised in your comment. It will make it so much clearer than currently